# Tmux viewport caused by multiple concurrent sessions

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

When attaching to the same tmux sessions from multiple computers using ssh and `tmux attach`, my screen looks like:

```
-------------------------
$>              |........
                |........
                |........
                |........
                |........
-----------------........
.........................
.........................
```

I was wondering if there is a command to get rid of the viewport

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814612/is-there-any-way-to-redraw-tmux-window-when-switching-smaller-monitor-to-bigger/20908246#20908246

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the width/height (colums/rows) of the "original" terminal form which you launched te tmux session is lower than that of the terminal you're attacching from. Personally I don't use tmux, but that happens to me with `screen` when I launch from a 80x25 terminal and then I attach from another terminal with 80x50 columns/rows.

Comment: Ya, I was wondering if its possible without detaching the other sessions to get rid of the viewport. Adding screen tag since it seems related.

Comment: I had a similar issue. I realized that I was connected to my tmux session on two different terminal windows, so tmux was using the dimensions of the smaller window. Once I detached from the 2nd window, the active tmux window automatically readjusted to use all the space.