# Tmux not scaling to fill the window

Tags: tmux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tmux viewport caused by multiple concurrent sessions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9132/tmux-viewport-caused-by-multiple-concurrent-sessions)

I have a weird issue where `tmux` isn't scaling to fill the window it's in:

[image]

I haven't had this issue before, is there something I need to do to get it to automatically scale to fill the host window?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My bad, I had it open in another terminal as well, and it only scales to fit the first connected terminal. I closed this window and opened the other one and it scaled just fine.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer your question. I had the same problem.

Comment: Press `CTRL-B` + `SHIFT-D` to disconnect a client of your choice.

Comment: alternatively you can detach all other clients except for the current one with `CTRL-B` and then `:detach-client -a`