# GNU screen :fit equivalent in tmux

Tags: gnu-screen, tmux

I'm experiencing [this problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9132) where I've attached a single tmux session at multiple terminals with differing console sizes.  Is there a solution to rid of the view-port without having to disconnect the other terminal, like screen's :fit command?  It seems rather silly that it is possible to attach tmux at multiple terminals and yet always have to use the lowest-common denominator of all terminals attached.

Comment: I'm also fine with an answer of "That's the screen-way of thinking, here's how you'd achieve a similar effect in tmux, without requiring you to disconnect current sessions and still being able to view each window or pane in another terminal"

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814612/is-there-any-way-to-redraw-tmux-window-when-switching-smaller-monitor-to-bigger

Comment: Thanks.  That answer seems to suggest that tmux does not have such a facility, by design (deficient by design :() - any session attachment indicates to tmux that it should display nothing or display everything.  Is that correct?  I honestly like screen's approach to handling this particular problem.

Comment: Yeah that was my interpretation as well (display nothing or everything). I use `screen` day to day, I've messed around with `tmux` to answer questions here and there but am used to `screen` myself. Use what works for you.

Comment: I also use screen day-to-day, but I was hoping to transition over to tmux (I'm more likely to contribute to it because of licensing concerns, it's more active in development, it's more likely to get ported to Interix, etc.).  Guess that won't happen real soon.